# Batch file to find a file using regular expression and rename it

Tags: batch-file, findstr, renaming

```
@echo 

cd\

cd C:\Test\pdf

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b | findstr /E /R "\\BW RRI - [0-9]\.[0-9]\PAYMENT CONFIRMATION.pdf$"') do set "Filename=%%i" ren ("%FileName%" "test.pdf")

EXIT
```

So i am trying to run above batch to find a file and rename it. Filename has space. When i run just the following command in command prompt it finds the right file

```
 dir /b | findstr /E /R "\\BW RRI - [0-9]\.[0-9]\PAYMENT CONFIRMATION.pdf$"
```

But when i use for loop to rename it, it does not work. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why you use in the for-loop the %%i and the %%a. I think this could be your error.

Comment: That was the typo as i was trying to change the name when pasting in stack overflow. Even when i use %%i only it still does not work

Comment: Do you actually have the `set` and `ren` commands on the same line? You can't do that.

Comment: The pipe symbol inside the for has to be escaped `^|`

Comment: ^| did the trick thank you!!

Comment: I'd add the `/I` switch to `findstr` to treat the file names case-insensitively like Windows does...

Comment: If you expect that your suggested and so far uncorrected `findstr` will match a filename from the `dir /b` command output, then I very much doubt that it will. As you are aware a backslash will escape the next character, this means that you are expecting a filename containing an illegal character and an integer followed by `AYMENT`… In addition I see no benefit in not using `Dir/B/A-D "*PAYMENT CONFIRMATION.pdf^| FindStr`…

Comment: @Compo, the single `\ `in front of `P` is simply ignored (as there is nothing to escape)...

Comment: I understand that, what I was trying to get at was that because `AYMENT` wasn't intended, there shouldn't have been an escape character there in the first place. Also because of the additional incorrect expectation of the file name beginning with a backslash, the entire command is wrong. I would suggest that the OP is really looking for a file named "PAYMENT CONFIRMATION.pdf" they should be doing a recursive search and matching ones which are found in a directory whose name matches "BW RRI - _i.i_" where _i_ is a single digit integer.

Answer (score 0):

3 errors.

First, the entire `for /f...` line will be parsed and any `%var%` replaced by its then-current value, so the `ren` clause will become `ren ("" "test.pdf")`

Second, the parentheses would be included in the parameters to `ren` and should be removed

Third, the `set` clause and the `ren` should be separated by `&` to cascade the instructions.

```
.... do ren "%%i" "test.pdf"
```

should fix the problem. There is no need to set `filename`.

Comment: So what do i change for the first issue  with for /f... ?